# Ibatis - Creating a table

Tags: ibatis, create-table

Most of the SQL statements appear to work with iBatis. Is it actually possible to create a table at runtime with an sqlMap statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a peep at the Ibatis in Action book it states

> DDL is not something that iBATIS supports directly. Although many people have successfully executed DDL using iBATIS..

Here's another example from the book, nothing on create though hmm...

`<statement id="dropTable">`
`DROP TABLE Account CASCADE;`
`</statement>`

`sqpMap.update("Account.dropTable", null);`

Although I have never attempted using DDL with Ibatis, found another link you may find interesting (curious to know the reason for using DDL though)

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.ibatisdb.user/4620

http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/wyq4ZKWL7Q69Rbv1Mygo

Comment: I managed to get it working (forgot that Oracle requires varchar2) in the way you've described. The reason I want to use a create and drop is to make a temporary table as a test. I'd already written some sqlMaps but for some odd reason my DAOs are outputting Maps instead of POJOs.